# How to run code once in a while loop

Tags: javascript

How do I run code once in a loop but loop the rest of the code? I have a GIF which changes to the moving, walking GIF on pressing the Spacebar. But it only runs maybe the first 3 frames then stops, then on release it changes to idle GIF, which is correct. It's just the walk sequence and I am guessing its because it is looping the code. Any help would be mighty appreciated.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){ 
    if (event.defaultPrevented){
        return; //do nothing if already processed
    }

    while (event.key === " "){
        window.scrollBy(10,0);
        break;
    }

    sprite.src = "images/sprite/walk.gif";

    event.preventDefault(); //cancel default action to prevent it being handled twice.  
})

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    if (event.defaultPrevented){ 
        return; //do nothing if already processed
    }

    while (event.key === " "){ 
        sprite.src = "images/sprite/idle.gif";
        break; 
    }

    event.preventDefault(); //cancel default action to prevent it being handled twice.
})
```

So, in a nutshell, all I want to do is want some code to run just once in a while loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: What's the point of a `while` loop where you always `break`?

Comment: A `while()` that always breaks is just an `if()`.

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop for the code that runs once?

Comment: And if you want to keep the event from bubbling, use `event.stopPropagation()`, not `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "first 3 frames then stops". There's nothing looping in the code you posted. Each time you press or release a key, the event handler just runs once. You change to the walk image no matter what key they press, but you only change to the idle image when they release the space key.

Comment: Sorry that sprite.src code is supposed to be in the while loop, forgot to move it back before I posted the question. And the reason for the break is because I am not an experienced developer, I thought break would stop it from crashing but I guess if the space bar is not pressed why would it still loop so I will remove that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your walk sequence, it's because every time the event is triggered you set the image, even if the image is already set ! So i have added a check condition before assignation.

Here is you sample of code lightly modified/improved :

**HTML :**

```
<img id="imgAnimated" src="http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dancing-banana.gif" />
```

**JS:**

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){

    if (event.defaultPrevented){
        return;
    }

    if (event.key === " " && $("#imgAnimated").attr("src") != "http://i.imgur.com/JfkmXjG.gif"){
        $("#imgAnimated").attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/JfkmXjG.gif");
    } else return;

    event.stopPropagation();
})

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
    if (event.defaultPrevented){
        return;
    }

    if (event.key === " "){
        $("#imgAnimated").attr("src", "http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dancing-banana.gif");
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jpmottin/0x937xcw/